# error LNK2005. It looks like a file is includet twice

Tags: c++

I want to write a little game using OpenGL and I have a `FileUtils.hpp` with a `ReadFile` -function and I have a class `ShaderProgram` which handles shaders and uses `FileUtils`.

Now, when I want to start the program I get this error:

> ShaderProgram.obj : error LNK2005: "`class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl ReadFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)`" (?ReadFile@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV12@@Z) already defined in Main.obj

I have not much experience with C++ but I think this error tells me, that my `ReadFile`function is defined twice. This should happen if you include a header-file twice which has no `#pragma once` or header-guard.

My `FileUtils.hpp` looks like this:

```
#pragma once  

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::string ReadFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    // File reading is done here.
    // Not important for this question.
}
```

My `ShaderProgram` includes this header:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <GLEW\glew.h>
#include "FileUtils.hpp"

// Shader stuff done here
```

And my `Main.cpp` includes `ShaderProgram.hpp`:

```
#include "ShaderProgram.hpp"
#include "Window.hpp"

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600
#define TITLE "Voxelworld"

#define VERTEX_SHADER_FILE "voxelworld.v.glsl"
#define FRAGMET_SHADER_FILE "voxelworld.f.glsl"

using namespace voxelworld;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Window window = Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE);
    ShaderProgram shaderProgram = ShaderProgram(VERTEX_SHADER_FILE, FRAGMET_SHADER_FILE);

    while (!window.IsCloseRequested())
    {
        shaderProgram.Use();
        window.Update();
        shaderProgram.StopUse();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`Window.hpp` includes neither `FileUtils.hpp` nor `ShaderProgram.hpp`.

I am pretty sure I just made a silly mistake somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the function is small enough to hopefully be inlined (in which case you should mark it as such) then don't *define* functions in header files, only *declare* them.

So in the header file do e.g.

```
std::string ReadFile(const std::string& fileName);
```

Then in *one* source file do the full definition:

```
std::string ReadFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    ...
}
```

---

The problem you have now is that the function will be *defined* in all source files ([*translation units*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) where you include the header file.

Comment: Also it is a good idea to use namespaces like FileUtils in current case

Comment: marking them as `inline` actually helps but produces another error... I thought I read somewhere that the compiler automaticly marks functions as `inline` when they should be. 
I just wanted to have it in a header file, because it is really small and its just for learning OpenGL.
Btw. I can't reproduce the error, since I now get this one: LINK : fatal "error LNK1168: cannot open D:\Development\Workspaces\C++\Learning_OpenGL\Debug\voxelworld.exe for writing"... but i think i can fix this one by myself :D

Comment: @Exhauzt That error is because the application is still running, you need to close it first before you can attempt to link it.

Comment: @Joachim it already was closed for a few seconds ^^ But i had to restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

With no class or namespace wrapped around it, ReadFile might be conflicting with the ReadFile in WinBase.h.  WinBase.h often ends up deep in your include tree.

Comment: I never includet WinBase.h and the error also happens if i rename it to `readFile`